# stack setup on openSUSE Tumbleweed

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

OS: openSUSE Tumbleweed up-to-date

As the stack documentation says, I can install stack using zypper from the default repository on Tumbleweed. The path to the bin is `/usr/bin/stack`.

I followed the stack tutorial on the official homepage and executed `stack new helloworld new-template` (which works). After `cd` into the folder, I tried to run `stack setup`, but this one fails with:

```
The GHC located at /usr/bin/ghc failed to compile a sanity check. Please see:

    http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/

for more information. Exception was:
Running /usr/bin/ghc /tmp/stack-sanity-check9034/Main.hs 
-no-user-package-db in directory /tmp/stack-sanity-check9034/
exited with ExitFailure 1



/tmp/stack-sanity-check9034/Main.hs:1:8:
    Could not find module ‘Distribution.Simple’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

After some googling I still don't know what to do to resolve the error. It's like I'm missing a very basic thing.

Comment: In the stack.yaml file, try add/setting `system-ghc: false` and re-runnin stack setup. You want stack to download and install its own ghc (which it will place in ~/.stack) and not use the system supplied version at /usr/bin/ghc.

Comment: Thanks. Please post this as answer so I can mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To force stack to download and use its own version of ghc (and other build tools), add:

```
system-ghc: false
```

to your stack.yaml file.

Comment: thanks man!! finally after 2 days I got the solution.. cheers!!